# Gas gauge reading incorrectly

Tags: pontiac, gauges

On a 2002 Pontiac Aztec, the gas gauge is reading empty after filling it up. How can I fix this problem? It’s been doing it for a while, but would show fuel report sometimes until recently.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It's either the wiring or the rheostat in the tank which reads the fuel level is at fault. The gauge itself rarely will go bad. I believe your Aztec should sweep the gauges as it does a power on self test (POST) after you turn the vehicle on. If the gas gauge moves during this, then it rules out the gauge itself.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your vehicle, but this is symptomatic of either a bad fuel float (it's stopped floating) or an electrical issue. Does it move at all or is it dead? Either way, to troubleshoot do a voltage test at the float. You need to find service info to know what reading to expect at empty.

Comment: Some gauges will read full if you earth the sensor wire, others empty, and still others may not like that as there can be a different arrangement.